# Reciprocal of power series with same radius

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $f$ be a power series $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ with radius $R=\limsup \frac{1}{(\sqrt{|a_n|})^\frac{1}{n}}$ defined in $]-R,R[$. Let us suppose that $|f(x)|>c$ for a given $c$.

Claim: Its reciprocal $\frac{1}{f}$ is always expressible as power series with the same radius $R$.

I'd like to have a simple proof through methods of basic analysis.

Comment: False, the radius can be larger. eg. $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z-z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{k+1} z^k$ where $F_n$ are $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number. $R = \frac{1}{\phi}$ but $1/f(z)$ is a polynomial, i.e. radius of convergence is infinite.

Comment: The radius of convergence is the distance to the nearest singolarity.  Consider the relation of singularities and roots.

Comment: Instead of "radius" you should say "radius of convergence".

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $f(x) = 1+x^2 > 1/2$ on $(-2,2),$ but the power series for $1/f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ about $0$ is $1-x^2 + x^4 - \cdots, $ which has radius of convergence $1.$